# How to clean Premake generated files using 'premake5 clean' command

Tags: lua, premake

To create a Visual Studio solution file and its respective project files using premake, I can type `premake5.exe vs2019` in cmd and it works perfectly fine.

However, when I command `premake5.exe clean` to remove all binaries and generated files created by premake it shows

Running action 'clean'...
** The clean action has not yet been ported

What do I have to do to make the clean action work? I'm really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can roll your own in your project script.

```lua
if _ACTION == 'clean' then
   os.rmdir('bin')
   os.rmdir('obj')
   os.remove('*.sln')
   os.remove('*.vcxproj')
   -- etc
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I added in my script and it works. But it is still showing "** The clean action has not yet been ported" in cmd prompt what can I do to make this message disappear.

Comment: Call your action something else? Submit a pull request to premake-core to help get it implemented?